# when i replace word in a .docx document using OpenXML dll gettin Exception `File Contains Corrupted Data` in C#

Tags: c#

Here my application i am converting .PDF file to .Docx document using that converted .docx file when i trying to replace word in that file i am getting Exception `File Contains Corrupted Data` how can i resolve this exception

i am using this code for replace word in .docx file

```
 public void Replace1(string path)
        {
            using ( WordprocessingDocument doc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
            {
                var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

                foreach (var para in paras)
                {
                    foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                    {
                        foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                        {
                            if (text.Text.Contains("Jumps to the beginning of the line."))
                            {
                                text.Text = text.Text.Replace("Jumps to the beginning of the line.", "XXXXX");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: This is already posted on http://stackoverflow.com/q/42218166/3048363

Comment: Hi @A3006, but i didn't mentioned clear information of my problem in previous post i need to check another way but here while opening the document is a problem

Comment: It seems that the path you are passing to `WordprocessingDocument.Open` is not in the format OpenXml is expecting.Are you sure that file is `docx`?

Comment: Hi @Pikoh, Here i have some pdf files those are converting into .docx files i need to replace the word in those converted .docx files. when i am trying to replace the word those are not open it raise exception`WordprocessingDocument.Open` here

Comment: How are you converting the pdf`s to word files? Are you 100% sure you are not converting them to doc format instead of docx?

Comment: we are using this `SautinSoft.pdffocuse dll` for converting pdf to .docx files

Comment: That does not say nothing to me. Try to open one of those word files with word, and look in the info what type of file is. The problem must be in the pdf-word converting part

Comment: Hi am converting pdf to rtf and rtf to .docx files